# Android AlertDialog in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

When I am using AlertDialog in ECLIPSE importing the followings

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

My application builds but it's not the view I want. I want to use

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

But after installing the apk the application crashes. What I am doing wrong?

Crash log (perdon my long crash log)

```
07-19 13:09:13.273: I/Process(17722): Sending signal. PID: 17722 SIG: 9
07-19 13:09:20.993: D/ResourcesManager(17894): For user 0 new 
overlays    fetched Null
07-19 13:09:21.023: D/JniHelper(17894): JniHelper::setJavaVM
(0xb815f940),  pthread_self() = -1225135284
07-19 13:09:21.063: D/Cocos2dxActivity(17894): model=SM-J510FN
07-19 13:09:21.063: D/Cocos2dxActivity(17894): product=j5xnltexx
07-19 13:09:21.063: D/Cocos2dxActivity(17894): isEmulator=false
07-19 13:09:21.073: E/SensorManager(17894): nativeGetSensorAtIndex:  
name,  vendor - 0, K2HH Acceleration , STM
07-19 13:09:21.083: E/SensorManager(17894): nativeGetSensorAtIndex: 
name,  vendor - 1, CM36672P Proximity Sensor, Capella Microsystems, Inc.
07-19 13:09:21.083: E/SensorManager(17894): nativeGetSensorAtIndex: 
name,  vendor - 2, SX9310 Grip Sensor, SEMTECH
07-19 13:09:21.083: E/SensorManager(17894): nativeGetSensorAtIndex: 
name, vendor - 3, Screen Orientation Sensor, Samsung Electronics
07-19 13:09:21.093: V/PTServicesBridge(17894): PTServicesBridge  -- INIT
07-19 13:09:21.113: W/PopupManager(17894): You have not specified a View 
to  use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity 
content  view. Note that this may not work as expected in multi-  
screen environments
07-19 13:09:21.123: D/AndroidRuntime(17894): Shutting down VM
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894): Process: com.tembo.huerun, 
PID:  17894
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr;
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at    
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:108)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:285)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
com.tembo.huerun.AppRater.showRateDialog(AppRater.java:63)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at   
com.tembo.huerun.AppRater.app_launched(AppRater.java:52)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
com.tembo.huerun.PTPlayer.onCreate(PTPlayer.java:52)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at   
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894): Caused by:  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class   
"android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.tembo.huerun-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= 
[/data/app/com.tembo.huerun-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.tembo.huerun-
1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at 
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at   
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at  
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    ... 17 more
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    Suppressed: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):        at  
java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):        at 
java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):        at 
java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):        at  
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):        ... 18 more
07-19 13:09:21.133: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    Caused by: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; 
no stack trace available
07-19 13:09:22.903: I/Process(17894): Sending signal. PID: 17894 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post your crash log

Comment: cant you just import what you want?

Comment: added the crash long log

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` . Please switch to Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

add the apcompact-v7 jar file in your lib folder.

Comment: Added without that it's give me can not resolve error